# What is the $menu parameter used of in wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: menus

I have a theme where I register multiple menus in function.php. All menus have a unique name and a simple description (we just use the name of the theme so they all have the same desc but thats ok).

In our templates we use the following code

```
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'sub_menu_manager', 'menu' => 'Manager', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'manager-menu', 'menu_class' => 'template-menu'));
```

Can someone explain what 'menu'=> 'Manager' does please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `menu` parameter is to get The menu that is desired and it accepts (matching in order) id, slug, name.

meaning in your case that the desired `menu` is named `Manager` but the `theme_location` parameter as the last word so if no menu is set in that location the menu will be the one named `Manager`